# Export Delphi BDE Paradox *.db Query Result to a text file?

Tags: delphi, export, text-files, bde

How to export Delphi BDE Paradox *.db Query Result to a text file?
e.g. 
I use SQL Explorer or Database Dekstop in Borland Delphi and the query like : SELECT * FROM mst_employee;

and I want the result of the query in a text file say mst_employee.txt something like :

```
employee_code;name;status;
001;Andi;1;
002;Budi;2;
003;Carli;3;
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate over the result set returned by the query and write the results to a text file, delimiting each file with a semicolon. I'm not aware of any built-in functionality which would do this.

```
with query do
 begin
  params[0].asinteger:= <whatever>;
  open;
  if not isempty then
   begin
    assignfile (f, 'c:\data.txt');
    rewrite (f);
    while not eof do
     begin
      writeln (f, fieldbyname ('a').asstring, ';', fieldbyname ('b').asstring, ';');
      next
     end;
    closefile (f);
   end;
  close
 end;
```

Apologies for old-style Pascal I/O, but if we're still using the BDE.....

Comment: actualy using textfile is also my alternative method but are there a method directly export to *.txt from the query result from SQL Explorer or Database Desktop or may be other? :) but thanks about the answer :)